# Acessing TextViews of Fragment from another Class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

in my project I have a class A that extends Fragment class and the class A holds two Textviews. the problem is I have to access the Tetviews from another class B , could anyone provide me a solution or hints how to do it.

sample :

```
class A extends Fragment {

    public TextView view1;
    public TextView view2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingsviewer, container, false);
        view1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        view2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        return view;
    }

class B {

    public void SetText() {
        view1.setText("Form1");??
        view2.setText("Form2");??
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Class B needs to hold a reference to those views or to the instance of class A itself in order to access them. I assume you are creating an instance of B within A? If so, pass the reference into B's constructor where you can save it to a class variable in B. How and where are you actually using class B in relation to class A?

Comment: Hi @NigelK thank you for the answer , I have got a reference of class A by passing the context into class B and then use to access the UI .

Comment: No problem. I've added this as an answer below, if you wish to accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class B needs to hold a reference to those views, or to the instance of class A, itself in order to access them. Assuming an instance of B is created within A, pass this reference into B's constructor where you can save it to a class variable in B for subsequent use.